# how to detect a fake user in refer and earn module in php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am going to create a module in my project which is based on refer and earn concept,i am facing one problem that , When user register and that user refer to someone we will instant pay to user who referred **but** the problem is that user can create fake account and can make money.so how to stop registering those kind of users in **PHP,Codeiniter** . what we did till now i mentioned below

**1. Captcha code 

2. Email Verification 

3. Authenticated by IP Address 

4. Unique link for each user and expire it after register new user By this link 

5. Authenticated By Cookie 

6. Authenticated by Computer Name** 


after done this a user can make a fake account and can get money from website.so what are rest points which i have to implement and can get fake users and block them while they try to register.

Comment: What kind of site is it? E-commerce? Then don't give out any money until the referred user has made an transaction? Otherwise, I think e-mail verification should be enough. Don't really see how points 1, 3, 5 and 6 would help you in this case?

Answer (score 6):

Captcha code - **Checks for human only**

Email Verification - **User cab create new email id again and again on** different sites

Authenticated by IP Address - **When machine change IP address changes**

Unique link for each user and expire it after register new user By this link - **When email id changes, it do not work**

Authenticated By Cookie - **works for a single system only**

Authenticated by Computer Name - **works for a single system only**

So nothing can help you in achieving your goal. According to me, you can add one more column in your database for **mobile number** and **send an OTP on mobile number if the number is now one**. Verify the user on mobile number basis.

**Note: This will also not reduce the fake users to zero, but minimizes it.**

Comment: Good suggestion with the mobile number.

Comment: gud to use mobile no. else there are many other such as getting official unique id for user details

Answer (score 0):

1. Use mobile verification.
2. Use OTP (One time password) when they try to log in. So they cant able to login except they have a valid phone.